# The "Mesh Boolean" node creates holes in the mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes

I created numbers that appear at the bottom and disappear at the top when they move (or vice versa) using a "Mesh Boolean" node.
[image]

Sometimes holes appear, which looks bad.
[image]

The options "Self Intersection" and "Hole Tolerant" do not help. Is there any other way to defeat these holes?

[image]

the file in which the problem is reproduced:

[image]

Comment: ...strange, I can't reproduce this behavior (tested with Blender 3.1 and 3.2). Can you somehow determine in which cases this error occurs or what this is roughly related to?

Comment: @quellenform there is the file in which the problem is reproduced: https://blend-exchange.com/b/POwoKyPj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't know what exactly is going wrong because I'm having trouble pinpointing the difference between the two files and what the error might be, but if I set it up a little differently, everything works fine:

[image]

- First, I would create the strings differently. Just use a single field, and enter the numbers there separated by commas. Then replace the comma with just a *Special Character*.
- Next I would apply `Mesh Boolean` directly to the text. This reduces the chance of errors.
- Finally I would extrude the mesh.

This way it works reliably and also much more performant.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: You solved my problem, but not in the way you thought. The problem was in the "Fill curve" node. I just switched to "N-gons" and the holes disappeared. Thank you.

Comment: @arachnoden ...yes, that was one thing, but that alone was not enough, because it still created some weird artifacts, triggered by that unspeakably slow `Mesh Boolean` node ;-)